# Can I reverse the two-finger scrolling direction in OS X Lion (10.7)?

Tags: macos, settings, ui

I just got 10.7. The two-finger scrolling direction seems wrong to me, although it says "direction - natural." I couldn't see a way to reverse it. Does anyone have a way yet?

Comment: I like the change. It's taking some getting used to, but I prefer the same experience between iPad and MBP when using gestures.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uncheck the box:

[image]

I found it unnatural, too, since they flipped it. I think they're going for consistency between iPads and mice.

Comment: I'll accept your answer as I was just being super idiotic assuming the check-box was to switch off two-finger scrolling altogether!

Answer (score 1):

Oh, found it: It's just the check-box, I thought that turned off two-finger scrolling, not the direction.

Answer (score 1):

I have an older Mac, and the option to change this was unchecking the first option under trackpad: "When using gestures to scroll or navigate, move content in the direction of finger movement."

Maybe this new scrolling direction is better, but for now I have two Macs, and only one on Lion, so they need to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

the option only available when i used magic mouse, my macbook was early 2008 model