# How can I change mouse button to work with Safari?

Tags: hardware, mac-mini

I got a Mac-mini but I'm not using Mac mice, I have a Razer Imperator mice. Checking under System Preference, there are only options that allow modifying scrolling speed, and tracking speed. So my question is how do I modify the left/right button of my mice since I want to navigate back and fourth between pages within Safari. Plus, I also want to change the scrolling behavior, it's completely opposite with Window, I scroll down, it goes up, I scroll up it goes down :(.

Comment: (1) Someone with a fancy mouse like you should answer this more completely, but you'll like [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html). (2) [Reverse the scrolling direction in Lion](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17795/can-i-reverse-the-two-finger-scrolling-direction-in-os-x-lion-10-7)

Comment: The scrolling is because it works that way on iPhone and iPad.

Comment: @JasonSalaz: I installed Razer driver for Mac already. I guess the USB Overdrive would do the same thing. My concern is how to go back to a page in Safari when hitting the side button of my mouse. I can get along with the awkward scrolling direction, but I do need the "back" button though. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/) you should be able to re-assign all the buttons as you wish for a particular program or system-wide.